# sso and slo on multiple applications

Tags: single-sign-on

We need to implement an single sign on and single sign out solution for multiple applications (not in same domain and different permissions per application) having one authorization server.

---

**Scenario 1**:

If we setup one `client_id: "global"` with scopes: "`app1,app2,app3`" on auth server user is authenticated in ALL apps and user has one cookie for auth server and one cookie for each app he opens.

Problem here is that a user that has access to `app1` and `app2` and NOT on `app3` is getting authenticated for all apps from auth server. So authorization should take place on application level.

Single sign out looks simple. Lets assume that user logout from app1, so he gets redirected to auth server and auth cookie is deleted. After he gets back to `app1.domain/logout` and app1 cookie is deleted as well. Authentication server is responsible to POST requests to `app2.domain/logout` and `app3.domain/logout` to delete all other cookies as well.

---

**Scenario 2**:

Each application has it's own client_id, for

  For example:
- client_id:"app1" with scopes:"user"
- client_id:"app2" with scopes:"user,public_repo"
- client_id:"app3" with scopes:"admin"

When user login through `app1`, code-token exchange take place with auth server by using as `client_id: "app1"`. Two cookies are now created one on auth server and another one for app1. When user now navigates to `app2`, another request take place by using client_id: "`app2`" and auth server is not able to authenticate user to app2 now. How is this feasible??

This setup does not look like and sso but looks more abstract than Scenario 1.

---

Any ideas/suggestions would be appreciated.

Thank you